# No mapping found for [added_on_value.sort_added_on] in order to sort on

Tags: magento2, product-sorting

I am trying to create new product attribute of type `datetime`. Attribute is created successfully and also there is no error while reindexing.
Note - I am able to save the attribute value from admin panel.

But while sorting I am getting below error -
`No mapping found for [added_on_value.sort_added_on] in order to sort on`

Please let me know if anyone has any idea what I am missing. Thanks in advance.